# How to pass results MVC 4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have a form which should pass the data to a next form. My method for form 1 :

```
    public ActionResult Order()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

the handler

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Order(OrderBegin booking)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Here i want to open a new form view and pass the result (booking) to the new form form
            return View(booking);
        }


        return View(booking);
    }
```

but how can i open a new view in the handler after (ModelState.IsValid)  while keeping the values that are passed from form 1.

To make the question more understandable i will explain what im doing.

first i make a form where you can select a value (example product 1)
if the value is valid i show a new screen where the user can type his name and also sees the cost of the product (value from form 1 needed here to calculate the cost). after submitting this form 2 i enter the data in the database (i still need the values from form 1 here)

Comment: As a side note, ViewModels should represent everything the view needs to render a view. I would really recommend not ever using the ViewBag, it's an extremely poor way to pass data to a view.

Comment: Thanks, i will change that later. Im using ViewModels for the OrderBegin btw. removed it from the question to avoid confusion

Comment: your that view is also strongly binded to this model which is in form1

Comment: Why is validation failing for the `Order2` method? You have already assigned the values of `OrderBegin` to `Order2` (e.g. `NextValues.CustomerID = booking.CustomerID;`) so if you have rendered inputs for those properties they should post back fine.

Comment: @StephenMuecke edited, i added some fields and made them hidden with jquery, apparently hidden fields are not passed.

Comment: Yes they are posted. But why make them hidden with jquery? Just use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerID)` to render a hidden control for property `CustomerID`. It will post back fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use TempData to transfer objects between requests. `TempData` uses internally a `Session`, so, after the redirects end, the session will be removed by asp.net mvc. For sample:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Order(OrderBegin booking)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        TempData["_booking"] = booking;
        return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", "SomeController");
    }


    return View(booking);
}
```

In the another method, make sure you have this object on the `"_booking"` key before using it, for sample

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    OrderBegin booking = TempData["_booking"] as OrderBegin;
    if (booking != null)
    {        
        // you have a OrderBegin object here, use it
        return View(booking);
    }


    // could return an empty view, or redirect to another place.. 
    return View();
}
```

Comment: As a side note, some of the CONs to using `TempData` is that you could lose data if the user decides to use the back button on the browser, or if the user uses multiple tabs then the user can also lose data.

Comment: Nice, but if i use another ViewModel in SomeAction i cant pass booking right ?

Comment: No, you have to give me treatments to lead with this. `TempData` is a `IDictionary<string, object>`.

Comment: @FelipeOriani see my edit, there is still a bug at the validation of form 2

Answer (score 0):

The two simple options are to have hidden fields on form 2 with the data from form 1 or session values.

It's very very important to know if you want to allow multiple paths or a single path.  If the user has 3 tabs open, the forms version can have 3 different values as each tab goes through your *wizard*.  If this is something that needs to be a single type event (like checkout process for an e-commerce site) then it should not use forms because you don't want them to; A be able to change the form values to invalidate the process and B each checkout process should be an [ACID transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).